# How to get column index matrix of an array in R?

Tags: r

Imagine I have a simple 4x3x2 array in R.

```
> x <- array(1:24,c(4,3,2), dimnames=list(c('a','b','c','d'),c('x','y','z'),1:2))
>  x
, , 1

  x y  z
a 1 5  9
b 2 6 10
c 3 7 11
d 4 8 12

, , 2

   x  y  z
a 13 17 21
b 14 18 22
c 15 19 23
d 16 20 24
```

What I'd like, is a simple function on the array that gives me back the name of the index of each element for an arbitrary dimension. In this case, dimension 2.

The function would behave like this:

```
> arraydims(x,2)  #Where 2 is dimension I want names for.

, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "x"  "y"  "z" 
[2,] "x"  "y"  "z" 
[3,] "x"  "y"  "z" 
[4,] "x"  "y"  "z" 

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "x"  "y"  "z" 
[2,] "x"  "y"  "z" 
[3,] "x"  "y"  "z" 
[4,] "x"  "y"  "z"
```

Comment: Does it have to be returned as an array? `library(reshape)` `y <- subset(melt(x), X3 == 2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function is just

```
colmtx <- function(x, n) {  return( array( 
                   rep(dimnames(x)[[n]], each=prod(dim(x)[0:(n-1)])), 
                   dim=dim(x) ) ) }
```

Comment: +1 - Yup, that's the version of my answer that's actually correct! ;)

Comment: I had an incorrect answer up for a few minutes, too,  but deleted it when I saw I had goofed.

Comment: Thanks - was trying to avoid the route of relying on knowledge of the array's implementation, but this works as intended and extends to n-dimensional arrays.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem to rely on knowledge of the implementation, but if you want to avoid it for some reason, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works as intended. My coding is probably a bit dodgy at best and there may well be a more straightforward solution.

```
arraydims <- function(arrname,arrdim) {

#rows

if(arrdim==1) {
arrname[,,] <- dimnames(arrname)[[1]]
print(arrname)
         }

#columns

if(arrdim==2) {
arrname[,,] <- rep(dimnames(arrname)[[2]],each=dim(arrname)[1])
print(arrname)
         }

#tables   

if(arrdim==3) {
arrname[,,] <- rep(dimnames(arrname)[[3]],each=dim(arrname)[1]*dim(arrname)[2])
print(arrname)
         }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it.  It gets the names for all dimensions at once (though that could be changed; I did it that way because the `which` returned all the indices anyway.

```
arraydims <- function(x) {
  x[] <- 1
  idx <- which(x==1, arr.ind=TRUE)
  lapply(1:ncol(x), function(k) { 
    array(dimnames(x)[[k]][idx[,k]], dim(x), dimnames=dimnames(x))
  })
}
```